# remove last 5 letters from class in jquery (not vanilla javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 dsitbl scrl_animxxxxx"></div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 dsitbl scrl_dd applexxxxx"></div>
```

I want to know is there any way in jquery to remove last "xxxxx" from class

Comment: You can remove that class and add a new class with updated name

Comment: no my friend i dont want to replace class , i want to remove only xxxxx not whole class

Comment: @yogendarji is right though. That literally is how you do it. You get the class name, strip the characters, remove the old classname and then put in the new one.... And the answers shown below show you how to remove the characters.

Comment: Is it always xxxx or can it be something else?  Is it always at the *end* of the classnames or might they appear in the middle

Comment: But *why* do you want to do this? It seems like a problem that would be solved by not abusing classes like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('class',$(this).attr('class').slice(0,-5));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 dsitbl scrl_animxxxxx">Abc</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 dsitbl scrl_dd applexxxxx">Def</div>
```

Note:-

***1.*** If you want to check first that class have `xxxxx` in it (at last) or not and then you want to replace,so you can do it like below:-

```
if (if ($(this).attr('class').substr($(this).attr('class').length - 5) == "xxxxx"){
  // remove characters code here
}
```

***Example:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').each(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class').substr($(this).attr('class').length - 5) == "xxxxx"){
      $(this).attr('class',$(this).attr('class').slice(0,-5));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 dsitbl scrl_animxxxxx">Abc</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 dsitbl scrl_dd applexxxxx">Def</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 dsitbl scrl_dd mango">Ghi</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is by removing the class then adding the changed class back to the element.

```
$('.applexxxxx').removeClass('applexxxxx').addClass('apple');
```

Comment: this is a manual way to remove xxxxx, but actually there are 55 different class contains xxxxx, then this code will not work